# Creating multipage PDFs from a list of open CV images: img2pdf and unicode issue

Tags: python, opencv, pdf, unicode, pdf-generation

I am attempting to add images (opencv) to a multipage pdf.

I noticed this can be done here:
https://github.com/josch/img2pdf

However, I also noticed that this latest edition of `img2pdf` is not capable of running after downloading and installing it via `sudo pip install img2pdf`.

After running the import I receive this message:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/img2pdf.py", line 187
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/img2pdf.py on line 187, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I attempted to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the `img2pdf.py` file with administrative privileges, but to no avail.

What can be done to make this package work?

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "to no avail" here? Did you get an error when attempting to add your coding declaration? Was your coding declaration on either the first or second line of the file? Have you tried issuing the plaintext version of that declaration ("# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8") instead?

Comment: Sorry - I meant it gave the same error after adding the `utf-8` flag at the top of the `.py` file. I was not aware of the  "`# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8`" version of the "`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`" flag, but that also does not work for some reason.